# Tavern Games for DnD

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, social, dice

Does anyone know any fun dice/card/gambling games that i can throw into my campaign for some good flavor?

Here are a few links to a [Reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/1kvv00/35_dnd_tavern_games/) that I posted and a [WOTC list](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/dg) of dice games.

If you've got any other good ones, please share!

Comment: Can you give us any criteria that's less subjective than "fun"? We don't field questions that can only be answered by opinion since our Q&A format and voting system isn't suited to such questions.

Comment: It has suggested that this may not be a duplicate. Querent, if you could refine your question so we may differentiate it, it may help when voting to reopen.

Comment: There is an "official" DnD-based card game, something about dragons.  Then, there's [this](http://xkcd.com/244/) classic xkcd...